# When we close the browser the session doesnot timeout, how to end the session

Tags: javascript, java, http

When we close the browser the session doesn't timeout, how to end the session?

Say we logged in and before session timeout we closed the browser. In that case the session is always there.

Comment: With no code example to provide any insight as to how you implement sessions, that question is about as useful as a chocolate tea pot.

Comment: Aren't sessions more or less a server side thing?

Comment: by setting timeout ....u can manage session

Comment: <session-config>
    <session-timeout>1</session-timeout>
</session-config>